# How can I build a DynamoDB table with efficient access patterns

Tags: database, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I am building an application where the data is stored in a DynamoDB table called UserInteractions and the users have a UI where they can filter by different attributes:

- Account: unique id identifying an account.
- User Type: an enumeration of 4 types of user types.
- Analysis Type: an enumeration of 3 different anaylisis types made or none when no analysis is made.
- Date Range: the date where the interaction has ocurred.

The table also contains an attribute called Date which is the timestamp where the interaction has ocurred.

There is an Index with Partition Key "Account#UserType" and Sort Key "Date".

The problem with the current structure is that the user can opt in for filtering by any combination of Account/User Type/Analysis Type. This forces us to do one query for each combination of Account and User Type selected with a Filter Expression for the Analysis Type. Which doesn't allow us to efficiently order by date and paginate easily.

Right now I was asked to add a new attribute called "Role Type" which also is an enumeration with 5 possible values (that might be increased in the future).

Is true that a user will more likely filter by account and not by the other fields but anything is possible from the current UI point of view.

How can I improve this design if I am able to make it from scratch? Maybe DynamoDB is not the right storage solution for my needs? Data can be huge and I need to efficiently filter by it.